# Move line starting with # to the end of next line. Preferred AWK or SED

Tags: sed, awk, merge, match, lines

I need to move every line starting with # to the end of next line ( AWK/SED ? ).

**Testfile.txt**:

```
# FIRST COMMENT
alias1: john@domain.com, tom@domain.com
alias2: betty@domain.com
# SECOND COMMENT
alias3: anna@domain.com, mark@domain.com
alias4: dan@domain.com
```

Expected output:

```
alias1: john@domain.com, tom@domain.com # FIRST COMMENT
alias2: betty@domain.com
alias3: anna@domain.com, mark@domain.com # SECOND COMMENT
alias4: dan@domain.com
```

I managed to do this that way ( but I'm sure it's not best solution ):

> sed '/^#/ N;s/\n/$/' testfile.txt | sed -e 's/\(.*\)$\(.*\)/\2 \1/

1. First SED merge line with next one with `$` separator.
2. Second SED switch everything between `$` character

Any advice how to make it better way ( performance & looking )?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to move every line starting with # to the end of next line

try this line:

```
awk '/^#/{x=$0;next}{if(x)print $0,x;else print;x=0}' file
```

or

```
awk '/^#/{x=$0;next}{print $0 (x? FS x:"");x=0}' file
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  echo "# FIRST COMMENT
alias1: john@domain.com, tom@domain.com
alias2: betty@domain.com
# SECOND COMMENT
alias3: anna@domain.com, mark@domain.com
alias4: dan@domain.com"|awk '/^#/{x=$0;next}{if(x)print $0,x;else print;x=0}'             
alias1: john@domain.com, tom@domain.com # FIRST COMMENT
alias2: betty@domain.com
alias3: anna@domain.com, mark@domain.com # SECOND COMMENT
alias4: dan@domain.com
```

Comment: I was about to post the same answer ...but...this i saw so a +1

Comment: Could You explain what does first example? I mean what happen after copying line with hash to x variable and going to next line.

Comment: @mike if a line beginning with `#`, save the line to var `x` then we go to next line, append `x` to that line, and print.

Comment: @Kent I meant a little different thing, but I solved it myself: If x is not equal to 0 then print whole (next) line and append it with x, else print whole (next) line, then after if statement set x to 0. :) Btw. is this solution also right? awk '/^#/ { getline t; print t,$0; next}; 1' testfile.txt

Comment: @mike, if it prints the expected result, it is "correct". but personally, I only use getline when I have to.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^#/{$!N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/}'  file
```

If the line begins with a hash, then append a newline and the next line (unless the current line is the last line in the file) and then swap that line with the current line and put a space between them.